# how can read values and put them in Array C#

Tags: c#, .net

I start dicoverig C# today ... 
as you know there is some difuculties

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
       int[] arr = new int[3];
            int i;
            for (i=0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = Console.Read();
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
            {
                Console.Write(arr[k]);
            }     

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

this code didn't work with me 
when i compiled it ...it make me put value for one time
then he print other values !
any one here to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      int[] arr = new int[3];
      int i;
      for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      {
        arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      }
      for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(arr[k]);
      }

      Console.ReadKey();
    }

  }

}
```

Bye.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
arr[i] = Console.Read();
```

try this:

```
arr[i] = (int)Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
```

`Console.Read()` will continue to read the same character over and over as it will still be considered the next character from the input stream.  The `Console.ReadKey()` function reads keys as they are pressed.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correcrtly this is what you want

```
int[] arr = new int[3];
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                Console.WriteLine(arr[k]);

            Console.ReadKey();
```